# angularjs selectize with integer model

Tags: angularjs, selectize.js

I am using angular-selectize2,

```
<selectize  config="mySelectizeConfig" options="my_array[id]" ng-model="myModel" >
```

On my controller

```
$scope.mySelectizeConfig = {
  maxItems: 1,
  labelField: 'name',
  valueField: 'id'
```

The my_array[id] object has an id with an integer value, 
But when I update the selectize dropdown the model is no longer an integer, it's a string.
How can I change this behaviour ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best option is to made your code work with it being an string instead of an integer. You can use [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) whenever you need to transform it.

If you really need it to be an integer, you can use the following:

```
  $scope.$watch('myModel', function(value){
    if (typeof value === 'string') {
      $scope.myModel = parseInt(value);
    }
  });
```

But becareful, I'm not sure if this work well in the version of selectize that angular-selectize use: [plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/dnGvfkXahS8Iw4XgWy3p?p=preview)